# Create box/rectangle shape based on two points/vector using python

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, draw-mode, gpu-module

I want to create a box/rectangle shape using two points while aligning to a given normal. The image below shows what I want to achieve. The left side shows the two  points supplied by the selected verts and the right shows the two missing points supplied by the intersection of the two points in the given normal vector.

[image]

Comment: Is the four orange lines are straight line ? First 2 points according to the mouse or the mesh data?

Comment: It could be mesh data or the mouse. I'm just interested with the intersection math. Yes, they're straight and based on the intersection of the two initial points creates a rectangle.

Comment: 4 points can't snap on some surface form to rectangle. But 3 points can snap on any surface form to triangle. Would you want to do it in flat surface only?